# Making RecyclerView vertical

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-alignment, android-cardview

Good day folk. I am new to Android. I have some issues with `RecyclerView`. I want to make appearance vertical for my data images and their texts, but it appears horizontal. I have already tried to write *orientation* as *vertical* in `RecyclerView` widget, it's `FrameLayout`, in `CardView`. Even I put *android:scrolbars* as vertical. But neither this nor that of them helped.

Here the horizontal result of `RecyclerView`:

**The resulting image**

[image: The result image]

fragment_blank.xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.fragments.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**CardView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview_id"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tovar_img_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="225px"
            android:background="#2d2d2d"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tovar_title_id"
            android:textColor="@color/redable"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Tovar"/>

       <!-- </ImageView>-->


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**UPDATE:**
RecyclerView initialization:

```
package com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.R;
import com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.adapters.Recyclerview_Adapter;
import com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.models.Tovar_tavsiya;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        //Tovar list BEGIN
        List<Tovar_tavsiya> lstTovar;
        lstTovar = new ArrayList<>();
        lstTovar.add(new Tovar_tavsiya("Modadagi kiyimlar", "Tovar kategoriyasi", "Description", R.drawable.tile_bg_1));
        lstTovar.add(new Tovar_tavsiya("Chet eldan uskunalar", "Tovar kategoriyasi", "Description", R.drawable.tile_bg_2));
        lstTovar.add(new Tovar_tavsiya("Tekstil mahsulotlari", "Tovar kategoriyasi", "Description", R.drawable.tile_bg_3));

        RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        Recyclerview_Adapter myrv_Adapter = new Recyclerview_Adapter(getContext(), lstTovar);
        myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
        myrv.setAdapter(myrv_Adapter);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: You might be taking `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`. Show your `Recyclerview` initialisation in java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
myrv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

instead of

```
myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you init this code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
your_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

in default the orientation is *VERTICAL*

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
Recyclerview_Adapter myrv_Adapter = new Recyclerview_Adapter(getContext(), lstTovar);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
//when you want vertical
layoutManager.setOrientation(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
myrv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
myrv.setAdapter(myrv_Adapter);
```

Comment: There is error with context. It has already worked, but anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

> recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,
> **RecyclerView.VERTICAL**, false)

> recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,
> **RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL**, false)